# Bootstrap menu in panel wraps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place a bootstrap menu inside a panel.  When the menu is outside the panel, the menu is rendered correctly with all menu items on a single line.  When the place the menu inside a panel, the menu wraps.

The code that generates the wraping menu is here:

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(58, 35, 3, 1);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(128, 78, 7, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(197, 198, 166, 1);
    background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #3a2303;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:800px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="/">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="sdfsdf">Mission</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="sdfsdf">Services</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="sdfsf">Partners</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="asdf">Education</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="sfsdf">Contact Us</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have also included a picture of what the menu looks like inside and outside the panel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f43fb34db53995f4b4397c59708dedb5

Easy fix; replace...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="max-width:800px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

with...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="max-width:800px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

Notice I moved the styles from your panel to the navbar

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:800px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

Fixed up your HTML a bit.

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(58, 35, 3, 1);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(128, 78, 7, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(197, 198, 166, 1);
    background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #3a2303;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="max-width:800px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mission</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Partners</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Education</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, Michael!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.